# MVC5 comparing two nullable dates with fluent validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

How can I write a rule in fluent validation to check two nullable dates in that the start date needs to be earlier than the end date.

I am thinking along the line of

```
RuleFor(c => c.StartDate)
            .NotEmpty()
```

if the start date is not empty and end date not empty then compare

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this-

```
RuleFor(ac => ac.StartDate)
     .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required")

 RuleFor(ac => ac.EndDate)
     .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required")
     .GreaterThan(r => r.StartDate);
```

**Note-**

The datatypes must be same for comparison.

**Or more convinient from this [source](http://www.onthefencedevelopment.com/blog/validating-startend-dates-fluent-validation-mvc-4)-**

```
 RuleFor(m => m.StartDate)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Start Date is Required");

        RuleFor(m => m.EndDate)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
            .GreaterThan(m => m.StartDate.Value)
                            .WithMessage("End date must after Start date")
            .When(m => m.StartDate.HasValue);
```

Comment: Error: `DateTime does not contain a definition for 'Value'` -- the `.Value` attribute cannot be used with any field that is a DateTime. This has clearly been depreciated with MVC5 and the latest Fluent Validation.

Comment: Just confirmed that the `HasValue` also does not exist for a DateTime, at least for MVC5 and the most recent Fluent Validation.

Comment: @RenéKåbis, You're right if you have DateTime not nullable. 
Note - In above case this is nullable I assumed. Or you can go smooth without `Value` and `HasValue` if its not nullable.

Comment: So, If i have error on end date for End date must be greater than Start date and i am showing it on screen. Then i change the start date, so that end date is not greater any more, still error wont go from screen because i have not changed the end date.How to handle that ?