# Fluent Validation Greater than or equal to dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Hi I am allowing a client to make events to display, those dates have `ToDate` and `FromDate`, I need to check the `ToDate` is in the future or the same as the `FromDate`; I used this fluent validation.

```
    public class EventDateValidator : AbstractValidator<Event>
{
    public EventDateValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(evd => evd.FromDate)
         .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required");

        RuleFor(evd => evd.ToDate)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required")
        .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(r => r.FromDate)
        .WithMessage("Date To must be after Date From");
    }
}
```

The only problem is that when the create form loads a null ref error is thrown:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   FluentValidation.AspNetCore.MinLengthClientValidator.AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context) in MinLengthClientValidator.cs, line 22

GreaterThan works just fine, but then if its a one day event validtion fails.

This is the first time I've used fluent, so my knowledge is very limited.  I actually used this question to get me started.

[MVC5 comparing two nullable dates with fluent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998626/mvc5-comparing-two-nullable-dates-with-fluent-validation)

Comment: Did you try enforcing r.FromDate as not nullable like: (r => r.FromDate ?? DateTime.MinValue)

Comment: No, I wouldn't even know how to implement that in fluent validation.

Comment: I tried adding a default value of DateTime.Now and DateTime.MinValue in the model, but no joy.  The problem occurs before the form ever even loads, not at validation, if that matters.

Comment: I made FromDate nullable, and then used what you suggested `.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(r => r.FromDate ?? DateTime.MinValue)` still no joy

Comment: Is your object you are validating `Event` or `EventDate`?

Comment: Event is the model name, I am validating ToDate making sure it is greater than FromDate.  I have since validated in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your original question with `MinLengthClientValidator.cs` and `Event.cs` sources, problem might be there - I'll edit final answer based on that. See implementation below, works fine with your inputs.

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Results;
using Shouldly;

namespace StackOverflowQandA
{
    public class FluentValidationTests
    {
        private readonly EventDateValidator validator = new EventDateValidator();

        [Fact]
        public void ToGreaterThanFrom()
        {
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new Event
            {
                FromDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
                ToDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15)
            });

            result.IsValid.ShouldBeTrue();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ToLessThanFrom()
        {
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new Event
            {
                FromDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 25),
                ToDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15)
            });

            result.IsValid.ShouldBeFalse();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FromToSame()
        {
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new Event
            {
                FromDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15),
                ToDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15)
            });

            result.IsValid.ShouldBeTrue();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ToIsNull()
        {
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new Event
            {
                FromDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15),
                ToDate = null
            });

            result.IsValid.ShouldBeFalse();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FromIsNull()
        {
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new Event
            {
                FromDate = null,
                ToDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 15)
            });

            result.IsValid.ShouldBeFalse();
        }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventDateValidator : AbstractValidator<Event>
    {
        public EventDateValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(evd => evd.FromDate)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required");

            RuleFor(evd => evd.ToDate)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("*Required")
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(r => r.FromDate).WithMessage("Date To must be after Date From");

        }
    }
}
```